# Collaborative itinerary Android+webapp, readable offline

Tags: gratis, android, web-apps, travel, itinerary

I often travel with friends, and we are looking for a convenient tool to plan/execute trips. It could look like this:

[image]

- Map-based (it can be list-based but at least it should have a zoomable map view of the data)
- Arrows showing the direction
- For each point, date of arrival
- Available as a webapp AND as an Android app, synchronized
- After synchronization, the Android webapp must be able to display the information even in places with no Internet
- Gratis, ideally open source, ideally using [remoteStorage](https://remotestorage.io) for storage

Bonus:

- Ability to add accommodation information (ex: hotel name, paid in advance or not) for each point, and transit information (ex: train name and changes, E-ticket). Unstructured text is great, support for images would be wonderful.
- Optional arrival precision up to the hour (when going through several points in a single day)
- Optional departure date (I should not be required to enter it, as usually it is implicitly the date of arrival to the next point)
- Ability to add "Places I want to go" independently from the general itinerary. Ideally with a small description (ex: I want to try this café's milk tea). Ideally people could upvote, and highly-upvoted places would appear bigger on the map.